# ¿como obtener el numero de sesion (que se supone es unico e invariable)?

Tags: php, session

He leido que si un usuario abre una sesión se le crea una ip única para su sesion, entonces he pensado que podría utilizar el identificador único de sesión para simular una ip. Quiero saber como retornar el número de sesión único que se le asigna a la persona que se loguea... Pero también quiero estar seguro de que ese código no va a cambiar nunca.

Answer (score 1):

Cuando se inicia una sesión en PHP se genera un ID único.

**Para obtener el ID de la sesión actual, en PHP,** (ID único) **se emplea la función: *session_id()***.

Si no hay sesión devolverá una cadena vacía ("").

**session_id()** permite cambiar el valor ID de la sesión actual. Se admiten caracteres en el rango a-z A-Z 0-9 comas y signos - (menos).

La ID no cambia después del inicio de sesión, pero puede ser cambiada mediante programación con **session_id()** o **session_regenerate_id()**, por ejemplo.

Más info sobre **[session_id()](http://php.net/manual/es/function.session-id.php)**

Comment: Gracias.Supongo entonces que tenia razon..se puede usar la id de sesion como ip :D

Comment: @user104554 puedes usar la ID de la sesión para componer URLs, no como IP, son conceptos diferentes. Un saludo.

Comment: me refiero a que, por ejemplo, si quisiera hacer una encuesta.

Comment: si quisiera hacer una encuesta, en lugar de capturar la ip, podria hacerlo con el id de sesion, que es unico ...de esta forma podria hacer pór ejemplo que una persona vote solo una vez

Comment: @user104554 creo que no vas a poder controlar eso si no creas algún sistema de autenticación de usuarios. Si usas la IP esta puede cambiar, incluso en la misma sesión, puede desconectarse de una red y conectar con otra sin cerrar el navegador... también puede haber varios usuarios compartiendo IP. La ID de sesión, esta asociada a la sesión, si cierras el navegador y vuelves a abrirlo o cargas de nuevo con otro navegador, tendrás otra sesión. Ya te digo que a no ser que el voto lo asocies a un email, nombre de usuario o similar, no podrás controlar que alguien vote repetidamente, e incluso así.

Comment: por eso pregunte si el id de sesion era permante o si variaba ..segun lo que dices, el id varia cada vez que cierras y abres el navegador..

Comment: @user104554 es un poco más duradera que eso. Acabo de probar y se mantiene en Chrome, cuando abres y cierras, incluso borrando cache. Pero es diferente entre dos navegadores. Y si abro una pestaña de incógnito la ID será otra, si la cierro y vuelvo a abrir otra de incógnito, vuelve a cambiar. Creo que es imposible que controles que no pueda haber más de un voto de la misma persona sin meterte en cosas complicadas de verificación de la identidad. Esto es como ponerle una cadena a la bici, que es para los espontáneos, pero si alguien se la quiere llevar se la lleva...